# Simple encryption and decryption of strings by using bz2 in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a file with encrypted username, password and computer name when the user logs in. And the same data I want to use again to authenticate the data but by decrypting them first. I am trying to use something that is built in python and simple.

```
import os
import bz2

os.chdir("D:/test")

encrypted_username = bz2.compress('username')
encrypted_password = bz2.compress('password')
computer_name = os.environ['COMPUTERNAME']
encrypted_computer_name = bz2.compress(computer_name)

f = open("Session.dat", "w")
f.write(encrypted_username + '\n')
f.write(encrypted_password + '\n')
f.write(encrypted_computer_name)
f.close()

f = open("Session.dat", "r")
data = f.read() 
d_data = bz2.decompress(data)
f.close()

print(d_data)
```

But when I decrypt the data in the file and print it. I get the answer as below. Why am I not getting the password and computer name?? Thank you.

```
username
```

Comment: You should `decompress` rows in the file one by one in a loop: `d_data = [bz2.decompress(row) for row in f]`.

Comment: Yeah I realized that read() command doesn't read the whole file. But sometimes the username or password gets too long that the data gets stored in the file in two lines. In that case, I get the error as   # Error: ValueError: file <maya console> line 3: couldn't find end of stream # How do I overcome this?

Comment: Encryption and compression are two different things.

Comment: I totally understand that.

Comment: Python does come with some simple encryption support built in, and there are third-party libraries like PySSL and PyCrypto that provide real encryption if you need it, so there's no good reason to be faking it with compression. If you just want a toy, `rot13` is a lot easier to debug than `bz2`.

Comment: By the way, you should use the context manager to open and close files.

Comment: Also, this is a bad approach for authentication. In generally, you don't want to store the password at all: store a one-way cryptographic hash that can be validated by a user-supplied password. See the [Cryptographic Services](http://docs.python.org/2/library/crypto.html) modules for more info, and the Wikipedia pages on [authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication) and the relevant links from there.

Comment: @abarnert Thank you for pointing that out.I should use 'rot13' instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code compressed the strings separately. You should read all lines and decompress them line by line as alecxe commented. But that is not practical because compressed data could contians newline(s).

Instead combine strings (In the following code, I used NULL byte `\0` as separator), then compress the combined string.

Decompress: After decompress, split combined strings using the same separator.

```
import os
import bz2

#os.chdir("D:/test")

username = 'username'
password = 'password'
computer_name = os.environ['COMPUTERNAME']

compressed = bz2.compress(username + '\0' + password + '\0' + computer_name)

with open("Session.dat", "wb") as f:
    f.write(compressed)

with open("Session.dat", "rb") as f:
    d_data = bz2.decompress(f.read())

print(d_data.split('\0'))
```

BTW, you should use binary mode to read/write compressed data.